# PHP reading Google Sheets but not refreshing

Tags: php, google-sheets

I am trying to use PHP to read a Google Sheet, which is publishing CSV to the web continually.  However if I change the data and then press F5 on my PHP routine, it only refreshes sometimes.  Even when I do an "Empty cache and hard reload" in Chrome it doesn't always update (but it does sometimes).  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
<?php
$spreadsheet_url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/my-id/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($spreadsheet_url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Google may cache result for You, especially when they clearly see robot (no UA/cookies/etc)
Instead of not stable WWW access use free API :

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Comment: Thanks, guess that must be it